# Qual a maneira correta de mapear um Dto com chave estrangeira?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tenho a seguinte entidade abaixo, ela possui uma chave estrangeira para a tabela Provider. Da entidade Hardware, criei as classes DtoRequest e DtoResponse e estou usando ModelMapper para mapear de uma classe para outra os atributos.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte, qual a forma correta de mapear o atributo provider na tabela Hardware já que é uma chave estrangeira?

```
@Entity
public class Hardware {
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
   private Provider provider
}
```

Devo passar desta forma?

```
public class HardwareDtoRequest {
  private Provider provider;
}
```

Ou desta?

```
public class HardwareDtoRequest {
  private Long provider_id;
}
```

Pois a maneira como fiz, ao realizar o metódo Post no Postman, tenho que passar todo os atributos da tabela Provider no body, queria passar somente o ID já que se trata de uma chave estrangeira.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A forma correta de mapear o atributo provider na tabela Hardware é utilizando o segundo exemplo que você mencionou, passando o ID da tabela Provider como um atributo do tipo Long na classe HardwareDtoRequest. Isso permitirá que você possa passar somente o ID da tabela Provider no corpo da requisição, sem precisar enviar todos os outros atributos da tabela Provider.

Caso você esteja utilizando o ModelMapper para realizar o mapeamento entre as classes Hardware e HardwareDtoRequest, você pode utilizar a seguinte configuração para mapear o atributo provider_id da classe HardwareDtoRequest para o atributo provider da classe Hardware:

```java
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<HardwareDtoRequest, Hardware>() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() { 
        map().getProvider().setId(source.getProvider_id());
    }
});
```

Comment: Meu Service está assim:

`public Hardware save(HardwareDtoRequest hardwareDtoRequest) {
  
  Hardware hardware = hardwareMapper.convertHardwareDtoRequestToHardware(hardwareDtoRequest);

  return repository.save(hardware);
 }`

Comment: No caso, estou fazendo da seguinte maneira o mapper:

`public Hardware convertHardwareDtoRequestToHardware(HardwareDtoRequest hardwareDtoRequest) {
  
 return mapper.map(hardwareDtoRequest, Hardware.class);
}`

Porém ao mudar no DtoRequest para Long provider_id, o meu método Post só cadastra uma vez com aquele provider_id, ao tentar criar outro cadastro com o mesmo provider_id, ele atualiza o anterior e não cria um novo. O que pode estar errado?